# Trying to run Android game using libgdx on Genymotion

Tags: android, libgdx, genymotion

Anybody experienced with libgdx and genymotion?

I'm trying to get a libgdx game running on genymotion android emulator - http://www.genymotion.com/

Everytime I try to run on genymotion I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:113)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61)
    ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:109)
    ... 17 more
```

Any Ideas?

Works fine with AVD

Android API 16
libgdx 0.9.9
Genymotion 1.1.0

Comment: is it running fine in the device? or are you getting the same error. seems .so files in armeabi & armeabi-v7a are not copied properly. open the apk and check the above files are in libs folder

Comment: It is running fine on real devices. I checked the lib folder in the apk. There are two folders armeabi-v7a and armeabi. In each there is a libandroidgl20.so and a libgdx.so. Other Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to add the x86 native libraries to your libs folder as mentioned in [this post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3103)

> To use the x86 natives, simply copy the x86/ folder from the nightlies to your Android project’s libs/ folder (next to the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folder). The setup-ui will not add those libraries for you automatically. I opted to do it this way for the time being as x86 Android devices are super rare, and you’d just blow up the size of your APK unnecessarily.

Comment: Spot on! I was running the emulator using Intel's HAXM virtualisation mode with AVD and this was why the libs weren't loading.