# Exception while running libgdx app on Android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to run a libgdx game on Android, but it's not working. I can run the desktop project without problems, but the app crashes when I try to run the android one.

I'm using Intellij IDEA, Debian Sid 64-bit and using a Nexus 4 to deploy the application (it also crashes when I use an emulator).

My colleague can run the application without problems. He's using Windows 7 64-bit, Eclipse ADT and running the app on Xperia ZQ.

I tried to follow the suggestions made on the answers below, but they didn't work for me, so any help would be appreciated.

[Trying to run Android game using libgdx on Genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549829/trying-to-run-android-game-using-libgdx-on-genymotion)

[Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806778/couldnt-load-shared-library-gdx-for-target)

Stack trace:

```
04-22 16:11:17.261    9615-9615/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sofq.candies, PID: 9615
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:104)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mypackage.myapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that are facing the same bug, I solved the problem by downloading the libgdx Gradle based setup application, which downloads all required dependencies.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html

Comment: I fixed it on IntelliJ IDEA by updating the Android Gradle plugin the project was using.